# pass direct ES6 module from index to TypesScript app

Tags: typescript, systemjs, es6-module-loader

I want to pass server side rendered config as ES6 module to a TypeScript application where it can be imported. using SystemJS module loader.

the config module is set directly in index.html:

```
System.set(System.normalizeSync('config'), System.newModule({ foo: 'bar' })); // in the real scenario the { foo: 'bar' } is rendered by the server
```

then in main.ts

```
import { foo } from 'config';
```

this works in the browser as SystemJS recognises the config module but the TypeScript compiler complains:

> Cannot find module 'config'.

how to tell TypeScript about the 'external' custom module defined in index.html?

Answer (score 2):

If `config` isn't typescript module (doesn't have types definitions etc) then it cannot be imported like this (it looks like ES6 import but actually it's not one). So either write `d.ts` file for it and place it somewhere `tsc` can find it, or try importing it in kind of "free form" with `let config = require('config')`. Then you can use it, but without any type hints and checks.

Comment: Where does the 'allowjs" directive fits in there ?